# Orchard CMS custom background job

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I created custom background job following [instruction](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B95dcjfaK38gQ3FsQk16Z2pwa1E/edit?usp=sharing).

You can see also [discussion regarding this problem](https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/455155).

Created task handler and constructor of task is called every minute. Process method is never called. Also I am getting timeout exception "Orchard.Tasks.BackgroundService - Error while processing background task".

It is interesting that it is possible to add new task, but any query won't work.

I checked table Scheduling_ScheduledTaskRecord and it was locked. I am getting timeout exception in code and SQL Management interface. Lock is released once I turn of site process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing Scheduled tasks, that run on the background. 
In order to trigger the execution of Process you need shcedule the first task (thus starting the loop). Use **DateTime.UtcNow** to schedule tasks.

You can also use Background Tasks, this way:

```
public class MyBackgroundService : IBackgroundTask {

    public MyBackgroundService() {
    }

    public void Sweep() {
        //Background task execution
        //DO some work
    }
}
```

Sweep() will be executed every 60 seconds. I don't know if this suit you, because this will be executed every minute even if the previous task is still running.

Comment: The first task is scheduled. Problem is that you can not query table. Timeout exceptions are thrown. I will try to use BackgroudTask, multiple tasks are not problem for me, I am processing Concurrency Queue.

Comment: Did not solve my problem but I got another working solution. Thanks